# How to hide PATH in Terminal in macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, path

I'm Running macOS High Sierra and recently noticed the entire PATH is permanently displayed in the Terminal (screenshot).

[image: prompt in Terminal]

How do I hide the PATH?

Here's the content of ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/
# export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/" #apktool for disassembling .apk files

source ~/.profile

if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac

# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I hide the PATH?

Change your `PS1` variable in `~/.bash_profile`.

> ```
> export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin
> ```

Note that the `PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin` part of the above line looks like it should be on a separate line (missing EOL after `$reset`).

The default is normally:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \W\\$"
```

Where:

- `\u` = username
- `\h` = hostname
- `\W` = current working directory

Comment: moving "PATH=$PATH:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin" down the next line fixed it. Your answer pointed me to the right spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**for macOS users:**

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

*at the end of the file add the following line and save it*

```
export PS1='\u:\w\$ '
```

*result at home directory:*

```
user: ~$
```

*here* 
u for user
w for current working directory 
$ is to prompt to display

you can try the following styles:

```
export PS1='$ '
```

*to just have $ as prompt, nothing else.* 
*just like:*

```
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your bash_profile and add the following line:

```
export PS1="\\[\033[33;1m\]\W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ "
```

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type and enter the given command line
`sudo scutil --set HostName texttodisplay`
replace texttodisplay with the desired name for displaying